# Ошибка в коде Python 'Microphone' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyaudio

При запуске кода пишет что 'Microphone' object is not callable и указывает на эту строчку:
`voice_input = microphone()`

**Вот код**:

```
import speech_recognition


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # инициализация инструментов распознавания и ввода речи
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()

    while True:
        # старт записи речи с последующим выводом распознанной речи
        voice_input = microphone()
        print(voice_input)


def record_and_recognize_audio(*args: tuple) -> object:
    """
    Запись и распознавание аудио
    """
    with microphone:
        recognized_data = ""

        # регулирование уровня окружающего шума
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(microphone, duration=[2])

        try:
            print("Listening...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(microphone, 5, 5)

        except speech_recognition:
            print("Can you check if your microphone is on, please?")
            return

        # использование online-распознавания через Google
        try:
            print("Started recognition...")
            recognized_data = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru").lower()

        except speech_recognition:
            pass

        # в случае проблем с доступом в Интернет происходит выброс ошибки
        except speech_recognition:
            print("Check your Internet Connection, please")

        return recognized_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Объект `microphone`, который возвращает `Microphone()`, не нужно ещё раз вызывать, его можно сразу передавать в `recognizer.listen()`:

```
import speech_recognition

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

with speech_recognition.Microphone() as microphone:
    audio = recognizer.listen(microphone)
```

https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.2.3/

Comment: можно вопрос а куда вставлять эти строчки кода?

Comment: К сожалению, пример с вашим кодом изобразить не могу: у вас в цикле созается микрофон, затем видно, что он должен использоваться в функции, которая никем не вызывается, и в которую он не передаётся. Похоже, нужно немного переработать скрипт, просто поправить не получится.

Comment: ясно, спасибо большое